# How can index a group of elements and return back an array of index in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, indexing

In my program, I want to find the index of elements in the array suit which is equal to 1. The IndexSuit function is going to do this and I expect to return an array from it which are the index of elements 1, say { 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6 }.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * IndexSuit(int suitofdeck[], int suittype);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int suit[13] = { 0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3 };
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        printf("%d", IndexSuit(suit, 1)[i]);
    }
}

int * IndexSuit(int suitofdeck[], int suittype) {
    int count = 0;
    int * index = calloc(13 ,13 * sizeof(int));
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 13; i++) {
        if (suitofdeck[i] == suittype) {
            index[count] = i;
            count++;
        }

        return index;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't look too far off.  What error/output are you getting?

Comment: You are mixing idioms: Do `malloc(13 * sizeof(int))` or `calloc(13, sizeof(int))`. You allocate 13 times as much as you need.

Comment: You return the array inside the loop, which means you catch only the first card. You also need a means to communicate to the caller how long the index array is.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have correct it. Now I can get { 2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} in output. By the way, how can I vary the array size base on the no. of elements I have found.

Comment: A good compiler would give you a warning for that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here seems to be where you have the return. It returns after one iteration of the loop. Looks like it should be on the line below.

There are a couple of other improvements though I'd like to suggest.

1) You are calling this function each time in your loop in `main` which is allocating memory and then you are picking one value out of it. I would suggest you call it once and then iterate through the array.

2) With your current code there is no way to distinguish between the index value of 0 and just not assigned ones (as there will be less than 13 index values and they are all initialised as zero). I would suggest that you return the number of indices actually set.

I've made a slightly modified version here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * IndexSuit(int suitofdeck[], int suittype, int* numIndicies);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int suit[13] = { 0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3 };
    int i;
    int* indicies;
    int numIndicies;

    indicies = IndexSuit(suit, 1, &numIndicies);
    for (i = 0; i < numIndicies; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", indicies[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(indicies);
}

int * IndexSuit(int suitofdeck[], int suittype, int* numIndicies)
{
    int count = 0;
    int * index = calloc(13 ,13 * sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 13; i++)
    {
        if(suitofdeck[i] == suittype)
        {
            index[count] = i;
            count++;
        }
    }

    *numIndicies = count;

    return index;
}
```

This produces the result:

```
2 3 4 5 6
```